How to edit a bootstrap navbar
I'm trying to modify the bootstrap Navbar, I'm still new to bootstrap btw.
Here's my html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NavBar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-primary">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="../images/ icon _bookmark book_.png" alt=""> NavBar </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Student</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Faculty</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </div>
      
    <script type="module"src="index.js"></script>

    
</body>
</html>


I have already set-up the basics (I already have scss and the other things required from the documentation of bootstrap), however I am still confused on how would I directly access these classes?
I tried creating a style.css to override the main.css. Also I want to be able to center the collapse class and I tried this
nav .collapse{
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;

}

However it didn't got centered
